# EmberJS many to many model association not being queried

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

"ember-cli": "0.2.7"
"ember": "1.12.0",
"ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.18"

I have defined a many to many relationship between my users and teams. Also, I have a relationship from my accounts to my teams (this is a one to many).

```
// user model js
teams: hasMany('team', {async: true})

// team model js
users: hasMany('user', { async: true }),
account: belongsTo('account', { async: true })

// account model js
teams: hasMany('team', { async: true })
```

I have a pod for showing an account and its associated teams. This works well but the problem I have is not being able to get my associated users of every team in my teams. It simply does not do anything at all.

```
// app / pods / teams / index / route.js
export default AuthenticationRoute.extend({
  access: ['admin', 'instructor'],
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('account', this.auth.get('currentUser.accountId'));
  }
});

// app / pods / teams / index / controller.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

});

// snippet from app / pods / teams / index / templabe.hbs
{{#each team in model.teams}}
     <tr>
         <td width="25%">{{#link-to 'teams.show' team.id}}{{team.name}}{{/link-to}}</td>
         <td width="20%">{{format-date team.startsAt 'DD-MM-YYYY'}}</td>
         <td width="15%">{{team.users.length}}</td>
         <td width="40%">{{team.licenseTemplate.name}}</td>    
   </tr>
{{/each}}
```

So the team.users.length are always returning 0 and it does not do a query at all like I am experiencing with teams on account (model.teams).

It has been working previously but after refactorization it has changed and I simply cannot figure out my problem.

Looking forward to your answers and help!